# CodingBat commonTwo method, help examine the output?

Tags: java, arrays

Question Summary:
Given two String arrays, return an integer representing how many matches are between them (ignore duplicates).

Real Answer:
http://www.javaproblems.com/2013/11/java-ap-1-commontwo-codingbat-solution.html

My Code

```
public int commonTwo(String[] a, String[] b) {
    int count = 0;
    boolean done = false;
    for (int i = 0; i<a.length-1; i++){
      if(a[i].equals(a[i+1])){
      i++;
        for (String j:b)
          if (a[i].equals(j) && !done){
             done = true;
             count++;
          }   
      }
      else{
        for (String j:b)
          if(a[i].equals(j) && !done){
             done = true;
             count++;
          }
      }
    done = false;
    if(i == a.length-2)
        for (String j:b)
          if (a[i+1].equals(j) && !done){
             done = true;
             count++;
          }
     }
  return count;
}
```

Image of output:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0esjC.png

So what it was intended to do was to go through all of the array a,if it equals the next one then go to that index, then add to count if there's a match between the arrays. The done boolean was used to make it so it doesn't add to count if there're duplicates of b that matches a and to end it once a match is found.

Lastly,

```
if(i == a.length-2)
```

was intended to make it so if it's the second before the last index number (as the last index number won't be checked in some cases), and not the same as the last index number, then it would check for matches for the last index number after checking the one before the last essentially. I understand why both errors occur and was wondering what could be done to fix it, particularly for the second one/comments on the code. Also, a third issue I notice would be (["a"], ["a"]) → 1 but the code will result in 0.

Comment: My code solutions in linear time, which is takes advantage of the fact that the two arrays are in alphabetical order.

Comment: Feel free for any queries.

Comment: Why not use break instead of the done boolean?

Answer (score 0):

This question can be done is linear time **O(N)** that is a single traversal of both arrays a and b.

You should increment `i` as long as same string appears.So

```
if(a[i].equals(a[i+1]))
      i++;
```

should be replaced by

```
while(i+1<a.length&&a[i].equals(a[i+1])){
      i++;}
```

**Also you do not need to go through entire array `b` for a single string of array `a` since both are in alphabetical order**.You should only compare the string from the array b as long there is no match.Once a match is found then you should remember that index and next time matching should continue from that index onwards for the array `b`

Also you don't need the boolean variable `done`.

Keeping these things in mind the correct code is:

```
 public static int commonTwo(String[] a, String[] b) {
    int count = 0;         
    int j=0,i;       
    for (i = 0; i<a.length-1&&j<b.length-1;){
      //SKIP DUPLICATES FOR ARRAY a
      while(i+1<a.length&&a[i].equals(a[i+1])){
      i++;}
      //SKIP DUPLICATES FOR ARRAY b
      while(j+1<b.length&&b[j].equals(b[j+1])){
      j++;}

      //MATCH THE STRINGS FROM ARRAY a AND ARRAY b
      while(i<a.length&&j<b.length&&a[i].compareTo(b[j])!=0)
      {
      //INCREMENT I IF STRING IN ARRAY a IS LESS THAN STRING IN ARRAY b
       if(a[i].compareTo(b[j])<0)
        ++i;
      //INCREMENT J IF STRING IN ARRAY b IS LESS THAN STRING IN ARRAY a 
       else ++j;
      }

      //IF ABOVE LOOP BREAKS BECAUSE OF MATCH
      if(i<a.length&&j<b.length)
       {count++; ++j; ++i;}
     }

    //IF THE LAST ELEMENT OF ARRAY a IS LEFT FOR COMPARISON
    if(i==a.length-1)
    {
     while(j<b.length)
     {

      //SKIP DUPLICATES OF ARRAY b
      while(j+1<b.length&&b[j].equals(b[j+1]))
       ++j;

      if(a[i].equals(b[j]))
       {++count;}
      ++j;
     }
    }
    //IF THE LAST ELEMENT OF ARRAY b IS LEFT FOR COMPARISON
    if(j==b.length-1)
    {
     while(i<a.length)
     {
      //SKIP DUPLICATES OF ARRAY a
      while(i+1<a.length&&a[i].equals(a[i+1]))
       ++j;

      if(a[i].equals(b[j]))
       ++count;
      ++i;
     }
    }
   return count;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution i could come up with that uses only one loop.

```
public int commonTwo(String[] a, String[] b) {
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    String s = "";

    while (i < a.length && j < b.length) {
        if (a[i].compareTo(b[j]) < 0) 
            i++;
        else if (a[i].equals(b[j]) && a[i] != s) {
            s = a[i];
            count++;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else j++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int commonTwo(String[] a, String[] b) {
        int ctr = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
                if (i > 0 && a[i] == b[j] && a[i] != a[i - 1]) {
                    ctr++;
                    break;
                } else if (i == 0 && a[i] == b[j]) {
                    ctr++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return ctr;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, maybe it would help to explain why your answer solves the problem.